# GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_handler_disconnect: assertion `handler_id > 0' failed

Tags: gtk, glade

What generally causes this?

What strategies can I use to track the problem down?

I have 6 buttons in a glade (gtk3.0) file - I see 6 warnings..., initially I wasn't getting these errors unitl after editing the glade file and making some (unrelated?) changes to my source - (I implemented an extra signal handler which amongst other things changes the buttons image to one of two (toggles) specified in the glade file)

Answer (score 0):

I tracked it down to some changes to unrealised widgets I was attempting to make.

In the end I had to comment out sections of code to gradually track down where the error was, the fact that even with debug info included the asserts don't give any hint of a line number is rather sub optimal....

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the image in a togglebutton when that button is toggled, right?
do like this:

```py
def on_foo_button_toggled(btn):
    if btn.get_active():
        // set image1.
    else:
        // set image2.
```

and bind this function to "toggled" event of that togglebutton.

Comment: I've never seen the point of toggle button when you can just change a buttons image in its clicked slot...  See my answer for what was causing the problem...